# Passing in Oauth token into headers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, github-api

Using the github api I am trying to pass in my token and I keep getting 'bad credentials' even though I know my credentials are correct.

```
fetch(contributors, {
    method: 'post',
       headers: {
          Authorization: //my token
       }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
       console.log(data)
 })
```

Comment: You are puting your token in corret format? 'Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN'

Comment: I tried this and it did not like it. `'Authorization: token 1j2olj109u812jlkj'`

Comment: Have you tried actually doing this with `"Authorization"` as far as your key? @pcproff

Comment: You may want to consider also sending in headers with your `"Content-Type": "application/json"`

Comment: @Maxcell I can see the Request Headers being passed in now with authorization: token mytoken but chrome is showing a 401 in network tab and "message": "Bad credentials"  `'Authorization': 'token kjasdlfjklaj'` is what I used.

Comment: @pcproff I am curious on which token you are using and the permissions you may have set. Are you using the [OAuth Application](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) or are you actually using your Personal Access Tokens, or you might be able to also utilizing the new Integration endpoint? Consider looking into [this in regards to what headers you are passing forward](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)

Comment: @Maxcell I am using the personal access token under settings > developer > access tokens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136502/discussion-between-maxcell-and-pcproff).